# Android ImageView scale and zoom replace image

Tags: java, android, imageview, scale, pinchzoom

I'm trying to build an simple image-zoom-replace functionality based on the Image-Zoom-Library "PhotoView":
https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

I just want to load a small image into a imageView and zoom/scale it. This code works perfectly:

```
ImageView galleryPictureNew = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.galleryImage);
PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(view);
mAttacher.update();
```

The problem is, i want to replace the small image with a large (hd-image) if i zoom in.

There is function called "setOnScaleChangeListener" like this:

```
                    mAttacher.setOnScaleChangeListener(new PhotoViewAttacher.OnScaleChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScaleChange(float scaleFactor, float focusX, float focusY) {
                        //REPLACE IMAGE

                    }
                });
```

This code above works, too BUT i want to "jump" to the last "position" and "zooming-level"?!

Does anyone has a solution for it? 
Or maybe someone has an alternative library for this problem?
Do i have to save the last "position-state"?